# Parsing XML within JSON

Tags: jquery, xml, json, yql

I'm using YQL to make cross-domain REST requests in jQuery. I'm getting the XML response I want as a key-value pair in the JSON response.

The request I'm making to is:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quickbase.com%2Fdb%2Fmain%3Fact%3DAPI_Authenticate%26username%3Dsomething%40intuit.com%26password%3Dsomething%26hours%3D24%22&format=xml&callback=?
```

The response I'm getting back is:

[image]

Now, my question is, how do I parse results[0] as an XML document? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Ashwin

Comment: does they support `format=json`, so no parsing will be necessary?

Comment: @Igor The API doesn't support JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
if (window.DOMParser)
{
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(results[0],"text/xml");
}
else
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(results[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var xml = $.parseXML( results[0] );
$(xml).find("qdbapi").each(
  function() {
     var action = $(this).attr("action");
  });
```